# Component doesn't see subscription changes

Tags: angular, ngrx

component.ts

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private store: Store<fromApp.State>
  ) {}
  loading: boolean;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.select('myState').subscribe(({ loading }) => {
      this.loading = loading;
      console.log(this.loading);
    });
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<div *ngIf="loading">
  loading
</div>

<div *ngIf="!loading">not loading</div>
```

In the browser console i can see the switch between the two states `loading=false` and `loading=true`. However, in the browser i always see "loading". What am i missing here?

Comment: What's the ChangeDetectionStrategy of the component? I suspect it's onPush?

Comment: Is OnPush the changeDedetction of one of his parents. Is that wrong? i Changed to "default" and now is working. Thank you, upvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the change detection cycle is not triggered when your observable is firing. It typically arises when `OnPush` strategy is used (-> improves performance because less detection cycles run, but you have to be more explicit about changes in counterpart).

So there are 3 ways to fix your issue:

- Disable OnPush strategies in your component tree (wouldn't recommend, you certainly benefit from it elsewhere)
- You explicitly run change detection cycle:

```js
constructor(..., private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {...}

// then in your subscription code:
this.loading = false;
this.cdr.markForCheck();
```

- You use async pipe in your component template code, because it plays nicely with `ngZone`: `*ngIf="loading$ | async"`, which means your loading observable is left as is: `loading$ = this.store.select('myState').pipe(map(s => s.loading))`.

Comment: Last approach (async pipe) is best IMO, manual change detection is hacky - framework should take care of it, plus it gets rid of the manual subscription which has its own gotchas.

Comment: I totally agree. Although manual cd is not hacky IMO, sometimes you have to use it, it's stable, well documented & predictable.